# finding /app folder in ubuntu

Tags: gimp

I installed GIMP 2.10 recently and wanted to install GMIC filter. The plugin folder from inside gimp shows /app/lib as in the image below:
[image]

but, I can't seem to find the /app folder, is this a virtual folder or something?

GIMP was installed using flatpak.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, somehow installing it with Flatpak or Snap won't let you access the folder.
Go ahead and remove it and install it with these three lines manually.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp`

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install gimp`

After that you are able to access the folder.